# Send SMS to Selected Contacts in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, abpeoplepickerview

I want to send SMS invite to multiple phone numbers selected from the contact list, I tried to use ABPeoplePicker but it is not coming correctly, my contact list is always showing blank.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

   UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showAddressBook)];

   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}

#pragma mark - Private method implementation

-(void)showAddressBook{
    _addressBookController = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
   [_addressBookController setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];
   [self presentViewController:_addressBookController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I feel I am doing something wrong, can anyone help me.

Comment: Are there actually any contacts?

Comment: Yes 160 contacts are there

Comment: I just tried this code in the simulator and it works fine. The only other reason I could think of is that you do not have permissions to access the contacts. However, this only applies if you're running this on iOS7. With iOS 8+, permissions are not required to access contacts from ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.

Comment: I solved this issue using UIActivityViewController it fulfilled my requirement of sending SMS to selected users. But still don't know why ABPEoplePicker not working